# View() does not function on subsetted dataframe

Tags: r, view, dataframe, subset

I have a simple problem: once I subset my dataframe to retain the observations I want to work on, it becomes impossible to View() said subsetted dataframe.

Basically, what I do is this:

```
df = data.frame(id=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","D","D","D","D"),
                sub=rep(c(1:4),4),
                acc1=runif(16,0,3),
                acc2=runif(16,0,3),
                acc3=runif(16,0,3),
                acc4=runif(16,0,3))
```

Then

```
df<-df[df$sub=="1",]
```

And if I now try to use the View() function, I get this message:

> Error in View : undefined columns selected

It does work with this specific example, but once I do it with my actual data, there is no viewing anything, although I can still use fix(), and I can still see the df in the console of course. Using the subset() function does not do anything to help me.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you post your actual data? Or better yet, reduce your data to the most simple `data.frame` that *doesn't* work.

Answer (score 0):

OK so I found the problem: I neglected to rename my columns, and I had multiple ones named NA.1, NA.2, NA.3, etc., I think the View() could not deal with the first one named "NA", so it gave me this error message. I used this and now it works:

```
library(data.table)
setnames(df,10:339,paste0("acc",1:330))
```